# Mounting unknown filesystem from LG TV

Tags: mount, hard-drive

I'm a new linux ubuntu user. I have a LG smart TV, Toshiba External harddisk and already recorded few TV shows inside that Toshiba External hd.

I want to mount that hard disk to ubuntu linux. So I can copy those TV show records. But I don't understand how to mount the disk into ubuntu.

Can somebody help me? Here is the output of fdisk -l screenshot, the toshiba drive is /dev/sdb1. From the screenshoot you can see that it is unknown in the filesystem.
[Output of my 'fdisk -l'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iZct9.png)

Comment: The file system type is "A2" - which is something an LG TV can read and write, but Ubuntu can't. However, it appears that an A2 type file system is in fact just an ext3 file system with a different label. Try `mount -t ext3 /dev/sdb1 /path/to/mountpoint`.

Comment: Thanks I understand. I just configured it now as mount -t ext3 /dev/sdb1 /mnt/sdb1, but its still returning same output: mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdb1, missing codepage or helper program, or other error In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try dmesg | tail or so

Comment: OK so we can't fool Ubuntu into thinking that it is an ext3 file system. What exactly is in `dmesg | tail`?

Comment: Yes, I think so. Ok here is the output of dmesg | tail : EXT3-fs (sdb1): error: can't find ext3 filesystem on dev sdb1.

Comment: This guy seems to have things working: https://www.avforums.com/threads/recording-on-lg-smart-tv-lm760t.1697353/

Answer (score 0):

Usually `mount` can autodetect the filesystem.  Have you tried mounting it with `mount`?

```
mkdir /mnt/sdb1
mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt/sdb1
```

There's a chance it's an unsupported filesystem, but most pre-formatted drives out there are some version of `FAT`, which is very well supported in linux.

Comment: Yes, I already follow your instruction and the output is like this: 
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdb1, missing codepage or helper program, or other error In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try dmesg | tail or so

Comment: Well if your TV is the same one as in the link provided by @Jos above, you may just need to mount it as JFS.  Try `mount -t jfs /dev/sdb1 /mnt/sdb1`.  However, even if you can get it mounted, the next battle will be figuring out how to play the videos.  If they're properly encrypted, you won't be able to.

Comment: Yes thats correct. There will be a next battle to go after mounted the disk such the encryption the smart TV uses in the recorded files or how to play the videos but once the disk mounted I will wait for community. I already followed your instruction and the output still the same output as above: mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdb1, missing codepage or helper program, or other error In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try dmesg | tail or so, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm very late to the party. Running

```
jfs_fsck /dev/sdb1
mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt/sdb1
```

fixed the problem for me. Apparently, the filesystem might be flagged as corrupted sometimes which is why mounting fails.

However, as the OP pointed out, the recordings are encrypted. Decrypting can be done using https://github.com/openlgtv/epk2extract but it requires you to dump the AES-128 key from the TV.